# Is it possible to reference self in a return statement

Tags: c#

I have a statement like this to switch the activation of an employee:

```
_dbContext.Employee.Where(x => x.id == id).First().Active = !_dbContext.Employee.Where(x => x.Id== id).First().Active;
```

Now I am wondering if there is something to simplify this to

```
_dbContext.Employee.Where(x => x.id == id).First().Active = !this.statement;
```

I know that it is possible to do this by putting it in variables but, I was wondering if this would be possible. I have tried looking it up but I frankly don't even know how to look for the solution.

Comment: Sorry, I could have clarified this better, it is used to swap an employees activation, from active to de-active and de-active to active. Therefor that wouldn't work.

Comment: For toggling you could do ```.Active ^= true;```

Comment: @Ascendise Nice! Sneaky use of XOR :)

Comment: Can you change the `Employee` source code? I'd be tempted to add a `.ToggleActive()` method for clarity.

Comment: @Ascendise Thank you, I never knew that operator existed.

Comment: I would say that a drawback of `^=` is that it might not be immediately obvious on first reading - hence my suggestion of adding a `.ToggleActive()` method, then it would be: `_dbContext.Employee.Where(x => x.id == id).First().ToggleActive();`

Comment: " I never knew that operator existed" - if so, then have your peers that are working on that project? (Assuming there _are_ peers) I do have coworkers that would complain about the readability of `^= true` ... just saying. It may not be obvious (to everyone) what this does.

Comment: ^^ Infact, just 2 weeks ago I had to write an extensionmethod called "EitherOr" wrapping an XOR because they could not wrap their heads around it :D

Comment: Consider using [ExecuteUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete#executeupdate).

Comment: The title has nothing to do with the actual question.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to toggle the Active flag on an employee that you're retrieving by key:

```
var employee = _dbContext.Employee.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
// handle null result
employee.Active = !employee.Active;
_dbContext.Save();
```

Answer (score 3):

> I know that it is possible to do this by putting it in variables

Not sure why you don't like variables, but you *could* do:

```
_dbContext.Employee.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToList()
    .ForEach(emp => emp.Active = !emp.Active);
```

So the normal way would be to use a variable, then you can also handle that there is no such Employee with the given Id:

```
Employee emp = _dbContext.Employee.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
if(emp == null) 
{ 
    // handle it: for example log it and return
}
emp.Active = !emp.Active;
```